# python matploblib graph not displayed

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

im new to python and im not sure why my bar graph isnt displaying anything. any help would be appreciated! 
dataset used: https://data.gov.sg/dataset/public-transport-utilisation-average-trip-distance

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ptrip = np.genfromtxt("data/public-transport-utilisation-average-trip-distance.csv",
                      dtype=(int,"U100",float),
                      delimiter=",",
                      names=True)

years = np.unique(ptrip["year"])

modes = np.unique(ptrip["mode"])

distances = ptrip["ave_distance_per_trip"]

avgs = []
labels = []
for c in distances:
    labels.append(c)
    mu = np.mean(ptrip[ptrip["mode"]==c]["ave_distance_per_trip"])
    avgs.append(mu)


plt.figure(figsize=(7, 6))
bar0 = plt.bar(labels,avgs,color="blue")
plt.xlabel("public transport")
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.ylabel("Average distance per trip")
plt.show()
```

Comment: What are you trying to calculate with mu? The `distances` array, according to the data set, should already be "average distance per trip". Are you trying to average the distance per trip per mode of transportation over all years in the data set, i.e. combine all the years?

Comment: You just want to plot the data set as x-axis = year, and a separate line/bar graph for each unique form of transportation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The calculation of `mu` looks wrong as `ptrip["mode"]==c` will always return false since you are comparing the strings in "mode" to float distances c. Thus your avgs array is just a bunch of nan values. This in turn is interpreted by matplotlib as nothing, therefore you plot nothing.

Edit: Although there are plenty of things you can plot from this data set, the simplest error I can find would be that you are looping through `distance` rather than modes. So working code for one plot (average distance per trip per mode of transportation over all years) would be:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ptrip = np.genfromtxt("/home/christopher/test/public-transport-utilisation-average-trip-distance.csv",
                      dtype=(int,"U100",float),
                      delimiter=",",
                      names=True)

years = np.unique(ptrip["year"])

modes = np.unique(ptrip["mode"])

distances = ptrip["ave_distance_per_trip"]

avgs = []
labels = []
for c in modes: # Note the change from distances to modes here
    labels.append(c)
    mu = np.mean(ptrip[ptrip["mode"]==c]["ave_distance_per_trip"])
    avgs.append(mu)


plt.figure(figsize=(7, 6))
bar0 = plt.bar(labels,avgs,color="blue")
plt.xlabel("public transport")
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.ylabel("Average distance per trip")
plt.show()
```

Comment: ohh i see. thanks alot man. may i ask how do you plot a histogram with this dataset? so far the only graphs i can think of is bar and line

Comment: @AoYang Glad to hear my answer helped you. If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as the answer and/or vote it up as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). As for your histogram question, please search the matplotlib documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/). If you have further troubles, you will need to start a new question, and be sure to be more specific about what is your problem as per the stackoverflow [asking guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)